# compare two strings in java

Tags: java

I am trying to compare to strings by using an algorithm as you see below
My code does not work .. eclipse does not show any error before I run the code

```
    public class MysteryClass {
    public static void mystery(String n) {
        String k= "alla";
            if (k.charAt(k.length())==n.charAt(n.length())) {
                System.out.println("palindrom");
            } else {
                System.out.println("not palindrom");

            }
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MysteryClass.mystery("alla");
    }
}
```

but we I run the code I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at shapes.MysteryClass.mystery(MysteryClass.java:6)
    at shapes.MysteryClass.main(MysteryClass.java:15)
```

How to fix that??
thanks

Comment: use `k.charAt(k.length() - 1)`.  charAt() is 0 indexed, so a length of 9 means you can call charAt() with 0-8

Comment: you are genious man ... God bless you :) thanks

Comment: you do understand that you are only checking the last character to check whether it is `palindrome` or not which is obviously not correct

Comment: NO I did not mean that ...I want to check all the sequence

Comment: You say you want to compare two strings, but only pass one into the method. --- You say you want to do it using recursion, but there's no recursive call. Anywhere. --- What is the relationship between "compare two strings" and "[palindrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome)" (word that reads the same backward or forward)?

Comment: I did my best ,, you can correct the errors ,, my code seems compare the last char and not the whole word ,,that is not what I want

Comment: Well, first you need to figure out what you want. Do you want to compare two strings, or do you want to check if a single string is a palindrome?

Comment: I want to compare two strings,

Comment: @Ali12 do you want to compare two strings for equality or what?

Comment: I want to compare two strings if they have same characters backwards and forwards for example word "alla" it is palindrom because you read it from right to left and from left to right .. that what I try to do !!!

Comment: if you want to check for palindrom, you must check all the string, not just the last/first letter...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you want, but your `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` is cause by access an array's index which is does not exist.

Take your `String k = "alla"` as example, `k.length()` will return `4` because `"alla"` have four characters, and you are accessing `k.charAt(4)`, the `"alla"`break into as follows:

```
a l l a  // string
0 1 2 3  // index
```

As you can see the last index of `"alla"` is `3`, that's why you get `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`. But you can solve it using `.length() -1` as follow:

```
 if (k.charAt(k.length()-1)==n.charAt(n.length()-1)) {
            System.out.println("palindrom");
        } else {
            System.out.println("not palindrom");
```

**Alternative:**

If you want to compare two `string`, you can use `.equals` method too, as follow:

```
 if (k.equals(n)) {
            System.out.println("palindrom");
        } else {
            System.out.println("not palindrom");
```

Answer (score 0):

Two issues with your code:-

1)By your logic, `tigert` is also palindrome but it is actually not.Palindrome is when the word is completely reversed and it is still the same.Currently,you are checking only the first and last character

2)String is internally held as a `char array` and arrays have indexing from 0 to `length -1`

Comment: OP is not checking `first and the last` but only the `last` if the index bug is fixed

Comment: I want to compare two strings not characters ,,,thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the statement  if `(k.charAt(k.length())==n.charAt(n.length()))` 
Above `k.length()` returns 4. the statement then resolves to:

```
(k.charAt(4)
```

This will through error because the function charAt counts from the index 0. So it counts the characters at index 0, 1, 2, 3 and you are asking it to fetch character at index 4 which does not exist.
A suggested alternative is :
`(k.charAt(k.length() -1)==n.charAt(n.length()-1))`

Comment: I want to compare two strings not characters ,,,thanks